# CLR/C# equivalent to XACT_STATE()

Tags: sql-server, transaction, c#, sql-clr

I am porting a set of T-SQL stored procedures to C#/CLR. In the T-SQL, we use XACT_STATE() to determine if an error requires rolling back to a savepoint or rolling back the transaction entirely.

I cannot find an equivalent check of the transaction using the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction` or `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` objects.

Does anyone know how to check the transaction state from within C#/CLR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XACT_STATE()` is not something that `SqlClient` has any special insight on, much like [transaction level](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/sqlinternaltransaction.cs,328). So, just query it with `SqlCommand`.

```
// If you already have an open connection...
public int GetXactState (SqlConnection connection)
{   
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select XACT_STATE();", connection)) {
        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. However, it depends on the internals of the *System.Data.SqlClient* assembly and so I would not recommend it. If it is truly required I would reassess if CLR is actually the correct way to do what you are trying to do.

The *SqlTransaction* is actually only a wrapper class around the *SqlInternalTransaction* class. The *SqlInternalTransaction* class already tracks the state of the transaction for you (if it didn't then how would the *SqlClient* know whether to rollback or not?)

You will need to use reflection to obtain the instance of the *SqlInternalTransaction* which again I would not recommend doing in a CLR procedure as this can be pretty costly in terms of performance - especially if it gets called many times.

That being said, here is how you do it.

```
public enum TransactionState
{
    Pending = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Aborted = 2,
    Committed = 3,
    Unknown = 4,
}

public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static TransactionState GetXactState(this SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

        PropertyInfo property = transaction.GetType().GetProperties(bindingFlags).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("InternalTransaction", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (property == null)
            return TransactionState.Unknown;

        object internalTransaction = property.GetValue(transaction);

        FieldInfo transactionState = property.PropertyType.GetField("_transactionState", bindingFlags);
        if (property == null)
            return TransactionState.Unknown;

        return (TransactionState)Enum.Parse(typeof(TransactionState), Convert.ToString(transactionState.GetValue(internalTransaction)), true);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlTransaction x = null;

        // use transaction etc.. here.

        TransactionState state = x.GetXactState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm is this value really accurate? For example if a statement on the server crashed and killed the tran, would this variable be updated in all cases?

Comment: Yes, it does. You would need to check it after each command executed against the transaction but the SqlClient library can handle dead transactions perfectly fine - indeed, there is even a method titled "TransactionEndedByServer" which handles this specific scenario.

Comment: I wish ADO.NET was exposing more of the TDS protocol. Command sets and the bulk insert ORDER hint come to mind as similar unexposed facilities.

Comment: This is quite nice. Thanks for sharing! And @usr : agreed, there are quite a few "private" properties and methods that should be public and I cannot figure out what the motivation was to keep them private. Things like the Collation info: LCID, CompareOptions, etc. The `SqlBulkCopy` class uses those things, so what is the harm in exposing those values to everyone?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky you are right. It feels to me like ADO.NET was done and forgotten. I also would like perf improvements. The CPU usage from reading big data sets seems disproportionately high to me. I have written many serializers and this seems too much.